# Prevent Multi-select in WPF Tab Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

It appears that in a WPF `TabControl` the user can select multiple items, either via <kbd>Ctrl-Click</kbd> or <kbd>Shift-Click</kbd>.

Is there a property that controls this?  Or do I have to handle the click/select event and explicitly unselect other items?

Comment: Are you sure TabControl is what you mean? Selector doesn't have any form of selection mode, and so multiple selection isn't available unless the control derives from ListBox, and even then the SelectionMode is still defaulted to 'Single'. Perhaps if you posed an example of what you mean it would be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Moore's comment, I was able to solve this.

Each `TabItem` in the `TabControl.Items` collection needs a control to display the content.  My program is using a `ListView`:

```
tabItem.Content = new System.Windows.Controls.ListView();
```

When creating each `ListView`, set the `SelectionMode` property to `Single`.
(Why that isn't happening, if `Single` is the default, is a mystery...)